# Ignore unbound properties for ConfigurationProperties in Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am running into an issue with unbound properties in my application.yml file. I am in the middle of migrating from Spring Boot 1.5.4 to Spring Boot 2.
My problem is that I have some properties which can optionally be left blank, for instance:

**application.yml**

```
app:
  enabled: false
  url: #ldap://127.0.0.1:3268
  user: #admin
```

In this case if `ldap.enabled` is set to `true`, then the `ldap` properties can be set to the needed values which are currently commented out. However, if `ldap.enabled` is set to `false` then the rest of the properties are not set and are left blank.

In my Spring Boot 1.5.4 application I didn't have any problems with this, but now after upgrading to Spring Boot 2 I get the following exceptions:

```
org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.UnboundConfigurationPropertiesException: The elements [ldap.ignorecertificate] were left unbound.
org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'ldap' to com.myapp.server.config.properties.LdapProperties
```

**LdapProperties.java**

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
@Getter
@Setter
public class AppProperties {

    private Boolean enabled;
    private String url;
    private String user;

}
```

I know I can set `ignoreUnvalidFields = true` in `@ConfigurationProperties`, but this is not exactly the behavior I want, since an empty value is valid in my case.

Is there a way I can ignore unbound properties? What can I do to avoid this problem?

**UPDATE**

After further debugging I can see that because `ignoreUnkownFields = false` in `@ConfigurationPropertes` then a `NoUnboundElementsBindHandler` is returned, which checks for unbound properties:

```
class ConfigurationPropertiesBinder {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private final PropertySources propertySources;

    private final Validator configurationPropertiesValidator;

    private final boolean jsr303Present;

    private volatile Validator jsr303Validator;

    private volatile Binder binder;

    ...
    ...
    ...

    private BindHandler getBindHandler(ConfigurationProperties annotation,
            List<Validator> validators) {
        BindHandler handler = new IgnoreTopLevelConverterNotFoundBindHandler();
        if (annotation.ignoreInvalidFields()) {
            handler = new IgnoreErrorsBindHandler(handler);
        }
        if (!annotation.ignoreUnknownFields()) {
            UnboundElementsSourceFilter filter = new UnboundElementsSourceFilter();
            handler = new NoUnboundElementsBindHandler(handler, filter);
        }
        if (!validators.isEmpty()) {
            handler = new ValidationBindHandler(handler,
                    validators.toArray(new Validator[0]));
        }
        return handler;
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can avoid this?